# OSX and iOS data type sizes

Tags: c++, ios, macos

Suppose I'd like to port a mac app (written in c++) to iOS, both in 32 bits.

Can I simply assume the data type(int, long, float...) sizes are the same?

Thanks,

Comment: BTW, an interesting read on this topic are the answers to the question [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot rely on them being the same. AFAIK they actually are in this case, but if you rely on a variable being of a specific size you need to use standard types like `uint32_t` instead to avoid any problems when compiling on different systems.

Be aware that starting with February 2015, Apple requires you to also provide a 64-bit version so even if you ignore the size problem for a while you'll have to fix it later on.